Matt 7:21 – Is Jesus addressing relationship vs. works or the use of gifts aligned with God’s will?
Text: Matthew 7:21-23 (ESV)

Not everyone who says to me, ‘Lord, Lord,’ will enter the kingdom of
heaven, but the one who does the will of my Father who is in heaven.
On that day many will say to me, ‘Lord, Lord, did we not prophesy in
your name, and cast out demons in your name, and do many mighty works
in your name?’ And then will I declare to them, ‘I never knew you;
depart from me, you workers of lawlessness.’

Matthew 7:21 is part of Jesus’ Sermon on the Mount (Matthew 5–7), where He concludes His teaching by emphasizing the importance of authentic discipleship and obedience to God’s will. Could this verse, then, serve 1) as a warning against self-deception and highlight the danger of what can be described as the "Lucifer syndrome”—the tendency to use spiritual gifts or works for self-glorification, much like the pride that led to Lucifer’s fall—serves; 2) as a stark reminder of the importance of humility and true alignment with God’s will; and 3) as a life lesson in walking in the ‘more excellent way’ of love (1 Corinthians 12:31) and humble service to God?

The OP's "spiritual" lesson from Matt 7:21-23 is only one of more than a dozen that can be drawn from this passage.

Why is the Father's answer "I never knew you" which contrasts with works?

I fully agree that our actions are extremely important as part of the divinely inspired process of salvation as James is at pains to teach.

@Dottard – Thanks for your input! Many see this passage as addressing "works" in the sense of synergistic cooperation or human effort. However, I believe it speaks to the difference between living and dead faith—what a person naturally does when given new life. Just as a living fish swims upstream, but when it dies, it can no longer swim, so too, the actions that flow from a born-again life align with the believer’s new nature through the leading of the Holy Spirit. It’s less about achieving salvation through effort and more about the organic outworking of a transformed life.

I do not see that here.  I see it simply as the difference between lip service and heart conversion.  That is the difference between a nominal Christian and one who has Jesus supreme in their life.

Urr... Can't it be both?

Yes, Jesus' words to the false disciples who claim to have prophesied, cast out demons, and performed miracles, all in the Lord's name, could indicate they are manifesting the Lucifer Syndrome (or Effect).
They may have started out with sincerity and good intentions, as perhaps Judas Iscariot did, but Jesus will one day pronounce them lawbreakers.
The thrice-repeated phrase "in my name" reminds me of Simon the sorcerer in Acts (8:9-24), who thought he could "buy the gift of God with money." He could perform many amazing works, but as soon as the citizens of Samaria heard the true words of evangelist Philip and witnessed the miracles he performed with God's blessing and ability, Simon likely lost many of his admirers.
The pharaoh's magicians mentioned in Exodus 7-8 were able to duplicate several of the miracles Moses performed with God's enabling.
We should not, then, be surprised that false disciples can perform "miracles" (more likely legerdemain). Jesus' number one criterion for prophets, demon exorcisers, and miracle workers is that they do the will of his Heavenly Father.
Jesus' mission in life was to do what his Father wanted him to do, in the Father's time and way. To Jesus, his daily sustenance was to do the will of the Father (John 4:34. For true disciples of Jesus Christ, Knowing and doing that will are made possible by the work of the Holy Spirit, who is resident only in true believers (2 Timothy 1:14; 1 Corinthians 3:16).

The simple answer is, "Jesus is addressing people".
The particular people he is speaking to (from chapter 4 verse 17 to 25) are multitudes of people from Galilee, Decapolis, Jerusalem, Judea and from beyond the Jordan river. They had thronged to meet this amazing man who had been teaching in their synagogues, preaching the gospel of the Kingdom, and healing all manner of sickness among the people; working miracles. Jesus had only very recently gathered his disciples.

"Then seeing the multitudes, he went up into a mountain: and when he
was set, his disciples came unto him: And he opened his mouth, and
taught them..." Matthew 5:1-2 A.V.

The next three chapters detail this foundational teaching his disciples would need to never forget in the years ahead.

"And it came to pass,when Jesus had ended these sayings, the people
were astonished at his doctrine: For he taught them as one having
authority, and not as the scribes. When he was come down from the
mountain, great multitudes followed him." Matthew :28-8:1 A.V.

The complex answer is: "Jesus is addressing the problem of how people should relate correctly to God, so that some will enter the Kingdom of heaven, otherwise, they will not."
A few verses before the text in question, Jesus has assured the people of God that their heavenly Father gives good gifts to those who ask him (in faith, it hardly needs to be said). Those ones must enter in at the strait gate, to get life everlasting, but few are the ones finding it, and entering. That is the point at which Jesus then warns his listeners to beware false prophets, and he gives identifying marks of such ones who have heard Jesus' words, but who have not done them. They are doing other things that - outwardly - grab peoples' attention and admiration, so that followers go after those false prophets. Those false prophets work miracles! They loudly proclaim that Jesus is their Lord! They declare they are prophesying in Jesus' name!
The only questions about them that need to be considered are, "What good is doing all those miracles and saying all those fine things, if that is not God's will for them to be doing? What has gone so seriously wrong that those ones will not enter into the Kingdom of God? Were they ever actually doing God's will, for how can anyone do God's will if they do not do what Jesus says they should do? Did they never find the strait gate, hence their never having entered in to life? How can a spiritually dead person help anyone who is seeking that strait gate so as to enter into the life of Christ?"
That is what Jesus is addressing to all who would listen to him, so as to never heed false prophets. Those who are in right relationship with Christ know his teachings, and faithfully carry the out. Holy Spirit gifts are given to all who belong to Christ by faith, and they learn to use them entirely for God's glory thus used in accordance with God's will.
The straight answer is that Jesus shows those who would listen that if they are to relate correctly to God and Christ, they must do what Jesus says and not be misled by false prophets; then they will be able to use their God-given gifts according to God’s will for them.

The verse refers to miracles like prophesying and casting out daemons. These aren’t deeds we do - God does them. That God performs such deeds through them can testify to their great faith - but it says nothing of what they themselves are doing to carry out God’s will.
The verse is in fact condemning only believing and not living accordingly. These great acts of faith are not what God has commanded of us. The analogy that follows makes this point explicit.
Matthew 7:24-27

Therefore, everyone who hears these words of Mine, and [t]acts on them, will be like a wise man who built his house on the rock. 25 And the rain fell and the [u]floods came, and the winds blew and slammed against that house; and yet it did not fall, for it had been founded on the rock.


26 And everyone who hears these words of Mine, and does not [v]act on
them, will be like a foolish man who built his house on the sand. 27
And the rain fell and the [w]floods came, and the winds blew and
slammed against that house; and it fell—and its collapse was great.”

I’m going to repeat that: everyone who hears these words of Mine, and does not act on them, will be like a foolish man
It is not sufficient to only believe - you MUST act according to what you claim to believe, you must live according to Christ’s teachings. Else, indeed, you are only playing the fool and deceiving yourself.


1 The context indeed confirms this interpretation. Miraculous demonstrations of faith mean little if they are not accompanied by "good fruit" (vs 17). As Jesus says in vs 12 "“Do to others whatever you would have them do to you. This is the law and the prophets."

